# background color telerik grid to excel

Tags: excel, telerik, kendo-grid

Is it possible to do this in another way or at least like this but with some more color options?

this works fine and does what I need but I also need more color options, here's the code

```
function excelExport(e) {

        var sheet = e.workbook.sheets[0];

        for (var rowIndex = 1; rowIndex < sheet.rows.length; rowIndex++) {
            var row = sheet.rows[rowIndex];

            for (var colIndex = 0; colIndex < (sheet.columns.length-2); colIndex++) {

                if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Weekend-") {row.cells[colIndex].format = "[Blue];";}
                if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Vacation Day-") { row.cells[colIndex].format = "[Yellow];"; }
                if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Holiday-") { row.cells[colIndex].format = "[Green];"; }
                if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Critical Task-") { row.cells[colIndex].format = "[Red];"; }

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer to this was simple, I just needed to replace `if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Weekend-") {row.cells[colIndex].format = "[Blue];";}`

with

```
if (row.cells[colIndex].value == "Weekend-") {row.cells[colIndex].background = "#1E90FF";}
```

to change the background of the cell